# iOS Master Detail App: detail view loads behind master view on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

I'm sure that this is just a silly mistake, but I cannot find the problem anywhere.

I have a standard master detail app that is working fine for iPad's, however, when I select a row from the master table on an iPhone, the detail view is loaded *behind* the current view.

**Before row selection:**

[image: Before Row Selection]

**After row selection:**

[image: After Row Selection]

I didn't even know that this was possible. Any suggestions to make the detail view load in front?

Comment: How do you set up things? in storyboard, or programmatically ?

Comment: storyboard. I followed the template master-detail application as closely as possible.

Comment: I'm going to guess there is something in `prepareForSegue:` causing the issue or something is pulling the table view back on top of the stack. In the simulator turn on slow animations and see if the view slides into place and then gets covered or not. Maybe make part of the table view transparent so you can see if the detail view is sliding in behind.